Bangladesh visa page torn. What to do?
An Indian friend got a visa for Bangladesh, but, unfortunately, his visa page was torn by a child. We used tape to put it back together. Will he still able to travel with that?


"Was torn" is not very descriptive, as we cannot see what you see. Take a picture of the torn page, and use the "Edit" button below your question text to add the picture to your question. If any personal information (name, visa number, etc.) appears in the picture, obscure that data before the picture is attached. This older question addresses damage to the passport itself, not a visa, but contains useful information about what constitutes "damage."

What did the VAC/embassy that issued the visa say when you asked them?

Thank you for adding the photo. What's on the reverse (unphotographed) side of the torn page?

I recommend not using 'was torn by a child'. It is irrelevant.

Very likely they can not travel with this visa, as a tear in any page of a passport is reason to reject it.
If it needs tape to stay together is (very likely) too much damaged.
Also see this question for samples, same as in the first comment.
Edit after seeing the photo:
With a tear like that I would suggest applying for a new passport and next a new visa, explaining that the visa page got damaged.
And in the future keep the passport out of reach of children.

Note that not only the visa is probably invalid, but the whole passport as well.
